# Angular2 issues in large application, lot of code in component making it slow and heavy

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular2 application(or let's call it angular), the application is fairly huge and I have a lot of code written in the component part. How can I make it lean and also use flux in it. I know flux is only single flow from child to parent but what about the siblings. Can someone please share some decent piece of code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.